# Plotting .log file containing timestamp and constant value

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, plot, sequence

I have a text file containing timestamps and values in two columns.
The data looks like this:

```
00:00:08    3.78E-7
00:02:10    3.78E-7
00:05:00    3.78E-7
00:06:00    3.78E-7
...
```

Since the values are not changing I want to plot the time. The chart should be a straight line.

I tried the following:

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import defaultdict
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import interactive


def main():
with open(r'C:\Users\sarad\leybold\230623.log','r') as line: 
 table = defaultdict(dict)
 for line in line:
   if line:
     entry = line.strip()
     if ':' in entry:
         t = entry
     for item in t:
          t1,t2=t.split(" ")
          table[t].update({t1:float(t2)})
 df=pd.DataFrame(table).T
 print(df)
 df.plot()
 plt.show()  
main()
```

When I print my DataFrame it looks like this:

```
15:19:37      15:20:07      15:20:37  ...      23:58:58      23:59:28      23:59:58
15:19:37 7.8E-7  7.800000e-07           NaN           NaN  ...           NaN           NaN           NaN
15:20:07 7.8E-7           NaN  7.800000e-07           NaN  ...           NaN           NaN           NaN
15:20:37 7.8E-7           NaN           NaN  7.800000e-07  ...           NaN           NaN           NaN
15:21:07 7.8E-7           NaN           NaN           NaN  ...           NaN           NaN           NaN
15:21:37 7.8E-7           NaN           NaN           NaN  ...           NaN           NaN           NaN
...                       ...           ...           ...  ...           ...           ...           ...
23:57:58 9.4E-7           NaN           NaN           NaN  ...           NaN           NaN           NaN
23:58:28 9.4E-7           NaN           NaN           NaN  ...           NaN           NaN           NaN
23:58:58 9.4E-7           NaN           NaN           NaN  ...  9.400000e-07           NaN           NaN
23:59:28 9.4E-7           NaN           NaN           NaN  ...           NaN  9.400000e-07           NaN
```

This is not possible to plot!

How can I import the .log file and edit the DataFrame so I can plot the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your data seems to be in csv format you can use `pd.read_csv(myfile, sep=delimiter)` functionality of pandas, where the `delimiter` is whatever character sequence is between your timestamps and the value (in this case it seems to be four spaces). Since the delimiter is not a single character (like `\t` for tab) you also need to set the `engine='python'` to avoid a warning in the console.

so try:

```py
import pandas as pd

def plot_log():
    # import .log file directly into a pandas dataframe and name columns
    df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\sarad\leybold\230623.log', sep='    ', engine='python', names=['time', 'value'], header=None)
    df.time = pd.to_datetime(df.time, format='%H:%M:%S',).dt.time  # cast column of timestamps as datetime object
    df.value = df.value.astype(float)  # cast column of values as float
    # set the timestamp as the index and therefore as the x-axis and display datapoints on line
    df.set_index('time').plot(style='o-')
    plt.show()  # display the plot

if __name__ == '__main__':
    plot_log()
```

Comment: @SaradinduSamanta Could you please pay attention to the last sentence of my post and clarify wheter the data you want to load is present in a tab delimited csv (meaning a text file with multiple lines of text where the columns are seperated by tab). If so you can save a lot of trouble by looking into the read_csv function of pandas.

Comment: Thank you. The following error is coming .                                                                           TypeError: no numeric data to plot

Comment: I am giving a slice of data ... Maybe it will be more clear . I could not give the data correctly in the first post.

Comment: 15:19:37     7.8E-7
15:20:07    7.8E-7
15:20:37    7.8E-7
15:21:07    7.8E-7
15:21:37    7.8E-7
15:22:07    7.8E-7
15:22:37    7.8E-7
15:23:07    7.8E-7
15:23:38     7.8E-7
15:24:08     7.8E-7
15:24:38     7.8E-7
15:25:08     7.8E-7

Comment: its like x axis and y axis ..... I xaxis there is time  (data with delimeter) then a space , then the pressure ....

Comment: please **edit your question** since formating is not really working well in the comments. You can try `with open(r'C:\Users\sarad\leybold\230623.log','r') as file:`  and then `lines = file.readlines()` inside it. Then print it in the console to check if each line is a seperate key value pair. If so you should be able to use the read_csv method from pandas.

Comment: have you tried my code samples? If not please do so (you should be able to just use them as they are. Just create a new .py script and past the code into it, no editing required) and tell us if it helps or what new errors occur

Comment: Yes, i tried your codes. I am giving you the outputs.

Comment: For the second sample the following error is coming....                                                          raise TypeError("no numeric data to plot")
TypeError: no numeric data to plot

Comment: For the first sample the following error is coming............................................................................... File "C:\Users\sarad\leybold1.py", line 13, in main
    data[parts[i*2]] = [float(parts[i*2+1])]
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '7.8E-7\n15:20:07'

Comment: I updated the input , mycode , and output in a proper way ..you can check it once. Thank you.

Comment: @SaradinduSamanta see my edit on the answer. try casting the type of the column as float since it is propably a string

Comment: Thank you. I ran the new code of you. It is giving following error.                                         return arr.astype(dtype, copy=True)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '15:20:37 7.8E-7'

Comment: try to use four spaces as delimiter and do not transpose the data. See my answer, I edited it again

Comment: I ran this code. The following error is coming.                                                                     raise IndexError("single positional indexer is out-of-bounds")
IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds

Comment: @SaradinduSamanta I have edited my answer again with some improvements. Pls take the code as it is and try running it again. If an error occurs provide me with the error message as well as the respective line that raised it. If my code answers your question mark it as solved, thanks.

Comment: ValueError: unconverted data remains when parsing with format "%H:%M:%S": " 7.8E-7", at position 0. You might want to try:
    - passing `format` if your strings have a consistent format;
    - passing `format='ISO8601'` if your strings are all ISO8601 but not necessarily in exactly the same format;
    - passing `format='mixed'`, and the format will be inferred for each element individually. You might want to use `dayfirst` alongside this.

Comment: The above error is coming....can not understand from which line it is coming....that line is not showing.

Comment: @SaradinduSamanta this error seems to be raised by the line which casts the time column. It seems that in som row or multiple rows of your log file there are values in the timestamp column. Please check your file if each line is always first the timestamp in the format hours, minutes and seconds, then four spaces and then the respective value.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind help. The program is giving the plot now.